# Return multiple function value to main() - C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to return multiple values to a function? In a program I'm working on, I wish to return 2 matrices to the main function, from a  function which is having 2 parameters,when the function called in main it will return values in 2 matrices all stats needed to continue through the program. I've found no way to really do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
for example

```
int main() {
   Matrix a,b=function(p,q);
   ...
}
```

Comment: mat a,mat b=function(p,q);

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. A C++ function returns a single value. But it can be of a composite type, such as... a pair of matrices. Alternatively, pass the arguments as pointers or references.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::tuple<Matrix, Matrix> function(int p, int q) {
   // ...
   return std::make_tuple(a, b);
}

int main() {
   Matrix a, b;
   std::tie(a, b) = function(p, q);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: @Priyanka using pointers how? If you have a different question you should make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

As always in C++ you have several posibilities. Here are some:

If you have a ever-fixed number of objects to return, add a struct with the appropriate number of objects, in your example:

```
struct FunctionResult { Matrix a, b; };
FunctionResult result = function(p, q);
doSomething(result.a, result.b);
```

If the number of objects to return is variable, return a standard container, for example std::vector, std::deque, etc. :

```
std::vector<Matrix> result = function(p, q);
```

If the meaning is appropriate and you always need to return 2 objects, you can return a std::pair, but it is better to use a dedicated structure so that you can name your objects with a meaningful name:

```
std::pair<Matrix> result= function(p, q);
doSomething(result.first, result.second);
```

In a similar manner, you can return a std::tuple so that you can do:

```
Matrix a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = function(p, q);
```

This might me the most similar to your suggestion and python but I would better use a dedicated structure because of the names. In all other cases, the correspondence between the returned objects cannot be enforced and being of the same type, I can imagine that they could get interchanged pretty easily.

If you want to use the [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) approach but have a compiler that does not support it, look at [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return more than one value, you may pass references to output storage as a parameter to your function.

```
void myFunction(int p,int q, cv::Mat& out1, cv::Mat& out2);
```

Comment: i need to return int p and int q and in main where myFunction(p,q)is called  need to get these values in other variables.

Answer (score -1):

Return a std::vector of smart pointers to the matrices.